# Terraform Azure KeyVault Key version - terraform v2.63.0

Tags: azure, variables, terraform, output, azure-keyvault

I am trying to enable disk encryption using "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension".

```
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "disk-encryption-web" {
      count = var.webvmcount
      name                 = "DiskEncryption"
      virtual_machine_id = element(azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.webwindowsvm.*.id, count.index+1)
      publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
      type                 = "AzureDiskEncryption"
      type_handler_version = "2.2"
      settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "EncryptionOperation": "EnableEncryption",
      "KeyVaultURL": "https://${var.envname}disk.vault.azure.net",
      "KeyVaultResourceId": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/ce-poc-terraform/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/${var.envname}disk",
      "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "https://${var.envname}disk.vault.azure.net/keys/diskencryptionkey/output.kvurl.value",
      "KekVaultResourceId": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/ce-poc-terraform/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/${var.envname}disk",
      "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
      "VolumeType": "All"
    }
    SETTINGS
    }
```

the property "KeyEncryptionKeyURL" needs the URL of the KV with the version number. I do nto want to hard code the version as It can change.
I can already get the version using

```
    resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "key" {
        name = "diskencryptionkey"
        key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.peripherialsdiskencrypt.id 
        key_type = "RSA"
        key_size = 2048
        key_opts = [
        "decrypt",
        "encrypt",
        "sign",
        "unwrapKey",
        "verify",
        "wrapKey",
      ]
      }
      output "kvurl" {
        value = azurerm_key_vault_key.key.version
      }
```

The output gives the version but I do not know how to take the output and put it in the "KeyEncryptionKeyURL" property.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the solution to the thign which I was referring to but I found another solution which is to use

```
${azurerm_key_vault_key.key.version}
```

so My URL looks like

```
""KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "https://${var.envname}disk.vault.azure.net/keys/diskencryptionkey/${azurerm_key_vault_key.key.version}"
```

And it works fine.